# How to use RL_ARM lib to design TCP project

Tags: c, embedded

Like the title,I want to use RL_ARM lib to create a project about TCP transmission.I now don't understand the structure of what I want clearly and deeply.Can any guy give a example to help me or give some suggestion.Thank you !

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I have tried some examples in ARM Forum.However,It doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe somewhere I config is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved by me and I configed the port 502.